# Is there any way to force a factory reset without being able to get into the bootloader nor the os?

Tags: factory-reset, android-12, nokia

I got a Nokia C100, when setting it up I messed up the password but didn't realize until I had locked the device, I can not log into the device, the bootloader only shows Fastboot mode, and android find my device is not finding the device at all. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to try get around this, that I know of USB debugging is not turned on so I have no idea if I can use any usb tools.